SQLAlchemy case-sensitive Unicode Column
The title does more or less say everything. I want to create a data model with SQLAlchemy and it should contain fields with values that contain unicode and should be considered case-sensitive.
Until know my type is sqlalchemy.Unicode(255) but e.g. in mariadb this results in utf8mb4_general_ci which is case-insensitive as far as I know.
So my question is how to define a case-insensitive unicode column in a database-independed way.

Does this answer your question? Case insensitive string columns in SQLAlchemy?

@ParmanM.Alizadeh , thanks,  I indeed had not found that question before, but it does not work, because the collation seems to be simply passed to the db, but there seem to be no collation that is supported by sqlite and mariadb (which are the ones that interesting me most)

"collation seems to be simply passed to the db" what do you mean by this?

Collation names (and by extension, behaviours) are not consistent across  DBs, unfortunately

@python_user The suggested duplicates top answer use the collation keyword of sqlalchemy.String, which seems not to be handled my sqlalchemy but is simply used as the collation for the database, but databases support non-overlapping sets of collations, so this is not a database-independend solution.

I have an answer here (also for case-insensitive alas) which covers similar ground.

@snakecharmerb I have noticed that, but that is the reason why I am using SQLalchemy, so that it can handle the differences between different engines for me.

@snakecharmerb So you answer is that there is no engine-independent way to specify that the case is relevant for a column.

Yes -  I think the easiest solution would be to create the database, with the required collation, outside of SQLAlchemy and then everything should "just work". But if you want to deal with collations inside SQLAlchemy then you will have to tolerate some database-dependent code.
